# spring boot jpa hibernate - fetch master detail data

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have two tables

```
ORDERS
ORDERITEMS
ORDERS will be having columns - ORDERS_ID, STATUS, TIMEPLACED,FIELD1,FIELD2,LASTUPDATE
ORDERITEMS is having columns - ORDERITEMS_ID, ORDERS_ID,PARTNUM,STATUS,FIELD1,FIELD2.
```

my requirement is to fetch the data in the below JSON format

```
{
   "orders_id":"1234",
    "status":"C",
   "timeplaced":"2018-05-10",
    orderitems:[
         {
              orderitems_id="7",
              orders_id="1234",
              status="C"
         },{
             orderitems_id = 8,
             orders_id = 1234,
             status='C'
         }
    ]
}
```

here ORDER details are like header in my response and items is an array of orderitems corresponding to that order id present in the header.

but when i use ManyToOne on the orderitems Entity, order details are repeating for every orderitem id. but that is not what i wanted. i want to have order details at the parent level and items details at the child level.

Is it possible with extending CrudRepository or should i go with HQL queries?
if it is possible, can you give me a way how to do that?